# Calculating non-orthonormal null spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab, octave

I am trying to calculate the null space of a binary matrix (GF(2)), but I don't want it to be orthonormal.

For instance, if you ask Wolfram|Alpha to calculate the null space of the following matrix:
\begin{equation}
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

It outputs:

[image: Wolfram|Alpha output]

I'm trying to get the null space with Octave/MATLAB's function `null(A)`. However, the result is what Wolfram|Alpha calls the *Orthonormal basis*, while what I want is just the *Basis*.

I know that $\sqrt{83} = \sqrt{(-3)^2 + (-2)^2 + ... + 5^2}$, but if I haven't got the values $(-3, -2, ...)$ I'm unable to reverse the process (or at least not without having to solve an equation system).

Is there any mathematical operation (or function similar to `null`) that I can use to transform it from orthonormal to non-orthonormal?

Comment: An orthonormal basis is a basis.  What you want, it seems, is a basis in which the vectors have integer entries. Is that right?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yep, that's it, sorry. I'm not very familiar with the nomenclature, I'll fix the question as soon as I can.

Comment: When you say "binary matrix (GF(2))", do you mean that you consider the coefficients to be in the field with $2$ elements $\Bbb F_2=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$? Because Wolfram Alpha and Matlab are certainly not doing that.

Comment: @Arnaud D. Exactly, they are modulo 2 coefficients. If I apply mod 2 to Wolfram's basis, I get the result I'm looking for.